# The speaker won't work for my Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4

My phone was working fine until one day I left it outside for a few minutes. I went back inside and checked my phone. I tried to watch YouTube but it had no sounds.

Comment: Did it get wet?  Do any other sounds work?  Did you try rebooting?

Comment: ^in addition to that, what sort of conditions were there outside? Warm? Humid? Hot? And did the phone physically feel any different (like too hot etc)?

Comment: It wasn't wet and the wheather was a little cold. I also tried to put on headphones but still had no sounds. Other apps didn't work too

Comment: Mathew thx for helping me.I rebooted my phone and now it works! 

Answer (score 0):

Did you phone get wet, or really hot? Connect a headset, if it doesn't play sound at all, reboot your phone.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh sorry I didn't read the comments.